# firebase ValueEventListener/onDataChange is only retrieving the last child node into the firebase recyclerview from the database and ignored the rest

Tags: java, android, loops, firebase-realtime-database

I have a fire node by the name of myHire which has a child which is identified by the current user id (whoever is logged in), The child further below the current user id node is the PostNode which can be anything and below postnode, lies the id,s of all those people who are interacting with the post. the postnode id and peopleInvolvedNode id in the postnode are not known to me by some specific identifier so i am trying to retreive their keys and values using  ValueEventListener/onDataChange loop. my problem arises when the the loop only retrieve the last node child and ignored the all the node which are above.

I am trying to solve this from a very long time. So any help would be appreciated
Thank You and have a nice day

This is my database structure to help understanding the question precisely

[image]

Below is my code

```
 myHire = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("My Hire").child(currentUserID);


myHire.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

               String checkKeys1 = child1.getKey();


                    Query query = myHire.child(checkKeys1);


                    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<hiredListDetails> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<hiredListDetails>()
                            .setQuery(query, hiredListDetails.class).build();


                    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<hiredListDetails, MyViewHolder> adapter =
                            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<hiredListDetails, MyViewHolder>(options) {
                                @Override
                                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final hiredListDetails model) {


                                    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: call 4");
                                    holder.topic.setText(model.getWorktitle());


                                    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: the topic is "+model.getWorktitle());




                                    holder.hiredPersonName.setText(model.getHiredpersonname());
                                    holder.hiredPersonBidPrice.setText(model.getHiredpersonprice() + " BD");

                                    String givenDateString = model.getCurrentdateandtime();
                                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy, HH:mm");
                                    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bahrain"));

                                    long timeInMilliseconds = 0;

                                    try {
                                        Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
                                        timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
                                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                    final CharSequence ch = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timeInMilliseconds, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

                                    holder.timeAgo.setText(ch);

                                    Picasso.get().load(model.getHiredpersonimage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile)
                                            .into(holder.hiredPersonPic);


                                    holder.requestTracker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            String clickedRecyclerKey = getRef(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey();
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked Recycler key is " + clickedRecyclerKey);
                                            String checkStatusForTracking = model.getActivatelocation();
                                            if (checkStatusForTracking.equalsIgnoreCase("True")) {

                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), TrackUserMap.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);


                                            } else {
                                                getLocationRequest(clickedRecyclerKey);
                                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please wait while the tracking process is completed",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }


                                        }
                                    });

                                    String checkStatusForTracking = model.getActivatelocation();
                                    if (checkStatusForTracking.equalsIgnoreCase("Request")) {
                                        holder.requestTrackerStatusMark.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.statusyellow));
                                    } else if (checkStatusForTracking.equalsIgnoreCase("True")) {
                                        holder.requestTrackerStatusMark.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.statusgreen));
                                    }


                                    loadingBar.dismiss();


                                }

                                @NonNull
                                @Override
                                public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hired_individual_row_layout, parent, false);
                                    MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
                                    return viewHolder;
                                }
                            };
                    myHiredList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.startListening();






            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: DO not use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` inside loop .

Comment: @ADM how can i go about solving my problem??

Comment: You are setting the adapter inside the loop. Try to get it outside. Does it work this way? Please responde with @AlexMamo